# Расположение текста в одной строке с <input>

Tags: html, bootstrap

Создаю форму в Bootstrap:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="edtURLpage" class="col-sm-3 control-label">URL </label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-5" id="edtURLpage"> qqq
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Текст "qqq" должен идти сразу справа за `<input>`, а он переходит на новую строчку.
Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 2):

Вот так заработало:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="edtURLpage" class="col-sm-3 control-label">URL http://</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edtURLpage">
        </div>
        <label for="edtURLpage" class="control-label">qqq</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Только определитесь, что является меткой (label) для input и второе сделайте span